# How to provide ILogger<ClassName> instance in new class object from controller in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, logging, ilogger

> As giving null it gives Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'logger') error.
> *Even if instance of model is given it still stays null*

```
 public class MyController : Controller
    {
            public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger)
            {
              logger.LogInformation("Log Testing");
            }

            public ActionResult List()
            {
                int Id = 5;
                MyModel model = new MyModel(null);
                model.GetItem(Id);
                return View("List", model);
            }
    }

public class MyModal:BaseModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyModal> _logger;
    public MyModel(ILogger<MyModel> logger) 
        {
           this._logger = logger;
        }

    public MyModel GetItem (Int Id)
    {
      try
      {
        //My Code
      }
      catch(Exception e){
       _logger.LogError(e.Message);
      }
    }
}
```

*As per the suggestion i edited my question*

Comment: Inject a Logger factory to the Controller and use it. Or create a ModelFactory ...

Comment: Does a _model_ even need a logger?

Comment: What @Llama said

Comment: On second thought, I agree with Llama. Since Models shouldn't contain logic, there wouldn't be much to log anyway.

Comment: @Llama, my model interacts with data layer so any error i get from data layer i catch them in my model

Comment: @Fildor, I do have logger factory for controller but it doesn't work for the model

Comment: _"I do have logger factory for controller but it doesn't work for the model"_ - so you're saying that injecting `ILoggerFactory` into the controller (as `loggerFactory`, for example) and then calling `loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyModel>()` doesn't work??? What error do you get?

Comment: _"my model interacts with data layer so any error i get from data layer i catch them in my model"_ - I'm inclined to think you have an architectural problem here.

Comment: @Llama ... or OP is using the term "Model" a bit differently from the common understanding of it in the "coding" community?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested in the comments:

1. Inject `ILoggerFactory` into `MyController` and store it in a field variable (e.g. `_loggerFactory`).
2. Use the factory to construct a logger for `MyModel` in your `List` method: `ILogger<MyModel> modelLogger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyModel>();`
3. Pass it into the `MyModel` constructor: `MyModel model = new MyModel(modelLogger);`

Example:

```cs
public class MyController
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    
    public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    public ActionResult List()
    {
        int Id = 5;
        ILogger<MyModel> modelLogger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyModel>();
        MyModel model = new MyModel(modelLogger);
        model.GetItem(Id);
        return View("List", model);
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vNq3Xl)